# issue with a calculator program in Tkinter with Python 3

Tags: python, tkinter, calculator

here is the code (see below for edits):

```
from tkinter import *

my_int_var = 0

def button_1_method():      #what's important is this method and the button_1 defined below
    my_int_var.set = my_int_var.get + 1
    entry_field.set = my_int_var

root = Tk()
frame_1 = Frame(root)
frame_1.pack()
frame_2 = Frame(root)
frame_2.pack()
frame_3 = Frame(root)
frame_3.pack()
frame_4=Frame(root)
frame_4.pack()

entry_field = Entry(frame_4)
entry_field.pack()

button_add = Button(frame_1, text = "add")
button_subtract = Button(frame_1, text = "subtract")
button_multiply = Button(frame_1, text = "multiply")
button_divide = Button(frame_1, text = "divide")
button_calculate = Button(frame_3, text = "calculate")
button_calculate.pack()

button_add.grid(row = 0)
button_subtract.grid(row = 0, column = 1)
button_multiply.grid(row=0,column= 2)
button_divide.grid(row=0,column = 3)

button_1 = Button(frame_2,text = "1", command = button_1_method())
button_2 = Button(frame_2,text = "2")
button_3 = Button(frame_2,text = "3")
button_4 = Button(frame_2,text = "4")
button_5 = Button(frame_2,text = "5")
button_6 = Button(frame_2,text = "6")
button_7 = Button(frame_2,text = "7")
button_8 = Button(frame_2,text = "8")
button_9 = Button(frame_2,text = "9")
button_0 = Button(frame_2,text = "0")

button_1.grid(row = 0)
button_2.grid(row = 0,column = 1)
button_4.grid(row=0, column= 3)
button_5.grid(row=0, column= 4)
button_6.grid(row=0, column= 5)
button_7.grid(row=0, column= 6)
button_8.grid(row=0, column= 7)
button_9.grid(row=0, column= 8)
button_0.grid(row=0, column= 9)

root.mainloop()
```

I am trying to add '1' to the number displayed in the entry whenever the 'one' button is pushed. however I am playing around with the button_1_method and getting various errors. How can I fix it so that whenever I press the one button, a '1' is added to the number in the entry (and the same with the rest of the number buttons)?

EDIT: I changed it a little:

```
my_str_var = StringVar()

def button_1_method(my_str_var):
    my_str_var.set(my_str_var.get() + 1)
    entry_field.set(my_str_var)


button_1 = Button(frame_2,text = "1", command = button_1_method)
```

now this is the error I'm getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/TOTTY/PycharmProjects/beginnerpoject/python calculator.py", line 5, in <module>
    my_str_var = StringVar()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 332, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 236, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

Comment: Don't say "I am getting errors" and make us guess what the problem is, copy and paste the whole error message (with traceback). The reason Python gives you all that info is that it's often useful.

Comment: Also, if this is a calculator app, I don't think you really want to add 1 to the number when the 1 button is clicked; you want to append a 1 digit to a string--or, if you want to think in terms of numbers rather than strings, you want to multiply by 10 and then add 1.

Comment: @abarnert ok I changed it and posted the new error message I'm getting now

Comment: The new error is because you can't create a `StringVar` before creating the `root`. (That isn't documented very well, so it's an understandable mistake…) Just move the `root = Tk()` to the top, and that will go away.

Comment: However, your code still isn't going to _work_, because you've got at least two other problems. First, you can't add the number `1` to a string. You can append the string `'1'` to a string; that's probably what you wanted. Second, you still haven't attached `my_str_var` to `entry_field` in any way. You probably wanted `entry_field = Entry(frame_4, textvariable=my_string_var)`. (See the example in the [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#patterns) docs.) And then you don't need to call `entry_field.set` (which is good, because no such `Entry.set` method exists).

Answer (score 1):

`set` is a *method*, which you have to *call*. And same for `get`.

So, instead of this:

```
my_int_var.set = my_int_var.get + 1
```

Do this:

```
my_int_var.set(my_int_var.get() + 1)
```

---

But you've got another problem on top of that. `my_int_var` isn't a Tk [`IntVar`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm), it's just a plain old int, which has no such methods. And it's also not attached to your [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm) widget in any way.

So, you need to create a Tk var with `my_int_var = IntVar()`, and then you need to pass it to the widget either in the constructor or in a `config` call.

If you look at the docs where you found the get and set methods, you'll see some examples that should make it obvious. In particular, see the third example under Patterns in the [`Entry`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/entry.htm#patterns) docs (but make sure to read the whole section).

---

There are other problems beyond the ones directly related to your error. For example:

```
button_1 = Button(frame_2,text = "1", command = button_1_method())
```

You want to pass the function, `button_1_method` as the command. But that's not what you're doing; you're *calling* that function, getting its return value, and passing *that* as the command. (It's exactly the opposite of your first problem, where you want to call a function but left the parens off. You can't expect Python to guess when you want to call a function and when you want to use it as a value; the parentheses are how you tell it to call the function.)

Similarly, as I mentioned in a comment, even if you get this all right, adding 1 to a number is not what the 1 key on a calculator does. You need to get the difference between a number and its string representation straight or you're going to have a lot more problems with this app. `1 != '1'`, but `str(1) == '1' and 1 == int('1')`

In your updated version, you've changed it to use a `StringVar`, whose value is of course a string, and you're trying to add `1` to its value. That's the same problem. Again, the number `1` and the string `'1'` are not the same thing.

And you're also trying to call a `set` method on an `Entry` object when no such method exists. Read the `Entry` docs to see how to change or replace the value of an `Entry`—but if you're using a `StringVar` (as in your edited code), you don't need to do this in the first place. That's the whole point of binding a variable to a widget; changes to either one affect the other. So, when you call `my_str_var.get`, you're getting the current contents of the `Entry` widget, and when you call `my_str_var.set`, you're replacing the contents of the widget.

Comment: @Laflexos: `int` is not the same type as `tkinter.IntVar`. You're making the same mistake as the asker.

Comment: First, I removed my comment right after your first edit. Soo, sorry. Other than that, I wrote my comment because in question it was `int` not because it should be. Thanks for explanation tho.